# How to center the chart vertically (using LineChart from mpandroidchart)?

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I am using *mpandroidchart* library to generate a chart but when drawn, it always appears more towards the top of the layout leaving a blank area below it. Is there a way to draw it to the center of the layout? (see image)

[image]

Also, *another question:* I have another chart which starts from x=0, y=0 but the values on y-axis usually start from (x= 0, y=15), (1, 16) or so. Is it possible to draw the chart from the minimum available y-index value(i.e 15 in this case) and not showing a blank area below it?

Comment: Why -1? I have read the documentation but it may be possible I have missed something that I probably didn't understand. Which is why I have asked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation of the YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-(YLabels)).

Focus on the following methods:

- `setStartAtZero(...)`
- `setAxisMaxValue(...)` & `setAxisMinValue(...)`
- `setSpaceTop(...)`
- `setSpaceBottom(...)`

Comment: After setting `setStartAtZero(...)` the chart starts on the minValue but the animation on y-axis still starts at 0. Is there any way to fix that?